# Pure JavaScript Prevent Keyboard Input/Click Until Timer Runs Out

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, timer

I'm new to StackOverflow, but I do come by fairly often to learn and figure some Javascript/Reactjs things.

I've made a script that is supposed to change the image, text, and description of an element and I was able to get a fade in/fade out script to make the objects fade out add the other new items and then fade back in.
The problem is that when you click the button/press the arrow key multiple times it will cause the fading effect to freak out and skip items.

I tried making a function that would run on an interval to preventDefault() every milisecond, but if preventDefault is placed inside the function it gives an error that it cannot preventDefault of undefined, and if you run it as an outside function (like in the example) it will just ignore the preventDefault() and run the console debug instead.

code:

```
function preventContinuence(func, time) {
    if (!(time) || !(func) || !(isNaN(time))) {
        var i = time;

        setInterval(function() {
            i--;
            if (i > 0) {
                func;
                console.log(i); //debug
            } else {
                clearInterval();
            }
        }, 1)
    } else {
        console.error('You did not include a function/time or the time is not an integer/float'); //This doesn't work... but it's not important.
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (modal.style.opacity == '1') {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                preventContinuence(e.preventDefault(), 800)
                FX.fadeOut(glryImg, {
                    duration: 400
                })
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.getElementById('glryImg').src = prevItem();
                    document.getElementById('imgTitle').textContent = title();
                    document.getElementById('imgDesc').textContent = description();
                    FX.fadeIn(glryImg, {duration: 400})
                }, 400)
                break;
    } else {return}
})
```

I've tried searching around on Google and on Stack to see if anyone else had an issue similar to this, but I could seem to find anything. It does HAVE to be in pure JavaScript because I'm creating the page with Reactjs and literally everyone on the internet tells you not to use jQuery or other libraries.

If it can't be done I know of another way to accomplish this, but I wouldn't be able to use keyboard inputs, which just wouldn't be fun.

**EDIT:** Someone pointed out to me in a Discord chat that you can use variables to prevent a script from running if there is an if statement. I was able to get the code working by adding a 'canPress' let and adding into the if statement if canPress == true run

code:

```
let canPress = true;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if ((modal.style.opacity == '1') && (canPress == true)) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                canPress = false
                preventContinuence(e.preventDefault(), 800)
                FX.fadeOut(glryImg, {
                    duration: 400
                })
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.getElementById('glryImg').src = prevItem();
                    document.getElementById('imgTitle').textContent = title();
                    document.getElementById('imgDesc').textContent = description();
                    FX.fadeIn(glryImg, {duration: 400})
                }, 400)

                setTimeout(() => {canPress = true}, 800)
                break;
    } else {return}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

React isn't too keen on manipulating to the DOM directly. I'd suggest looking into and coming up with a solution using the UseState and UseEffect hooks.

For example, one approach would be:

1. Initializing a loading state using the useState hook.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

2. Then with the useEffect hook, you could listen for the key event.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
});
```

3. Then use the handleKey function to run your program, etc.

```
const handleKey = (e) => {
  const arrow = e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39
  if (arrow && !loading) {
    setLoading(true)
    // Do some stuff . . . 
    setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

4. Then in the actual components body you would just set a ternary using the loading state to determine the view of the component.

P.S. This isn't perfect, but could serve as a good starting point. I'd highly suggest diving into the [React hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Comment: I actually do use the useEffect hook in my react code, but this code loads into the DOM when the <App /> is mounted.
I wrote this javascript file years ago and it has many other functions in it beside this that I didn't want to clutter my React code with.